# How to determine the type of generic in a class?

Tags: typescript, generics

If I have a class such as

```js
class Foo<T>{}
```

How do I check what type the instance of the class is in the method? Meaning, something like

```js
public barbaz(){
  // Does not work
  if(typeof(<T>) === 'number'){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix the type and values, but I know sometimes this feature was helpful. But we are in a superset of language (JS) which doesn't have any called "Type parameters".
Somewhere (constructor, setter) you must use a parameter with type "T".

Something Like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
   constructor(public type: T) {}
   public barbaz(){
     // works
     if(typeof this.type === 'number'){}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

THere is workaround here.
Take a look on next example:

```js
interface HandleNumbers {
  add(arg: number): number
}

interface HandleStrings {
  concat(a: string, b: string): string;
}

class Api {
  add = (arg: number) => arg + 1
  concat = (a: string, b: string) => a.concat(b)
}

interface HandleHttp {
  <T extends void>(): {};
  <T extends string>(): HandleStrings;
  <T extends number>(): HandleNumbers;
}

const handleHttp: HandleHttp = <_ extends string | number>() => new Api();

handleHttp<number>() // you can only call [add] method
handleHttp<string>() // you can only call [concat] method
handleHttp() // unable to call any method
```

Please keep in mind, your generated JS code will contain both methods `add` and `concat`.

So, in some way, your ability to call methods depends on provided generic

Yo can read more [here](http://catchts.com/api)