# Why can't i assign class to type with less properties?

Tags: typescript

In the following example:

```
class C<T extends string = string> {
  constructor(public tag: T) {}
  static create<P extends string = string>(tag: P): string extends P ? Omit<C<P>, 'tag'> : C<P> {
    return new C<P>(tag);
  }
}
```

I get the error:

> Type 'C<P>' is not assignable to type 'string extends P ? Pick<C<P>, never> : C<P>'.

Which i don't understand. `C<P>` should be assignable to a type with just less properties, and to itself?

Edit: I also tried `[string] extends [P] ? Omit<C<P>, 'tag'> : C<P>` in case there was some weird union i didn't understand, but it doesn't work either.

Edit2: There was an overlapping error, for the `C<P>('')` default i missed. Changed `tag` to be non-optional to have a default value.

Edit3: While not sure yet, i think it's related to there generally being little to no code flow analysis or constraining regarding conditional types, and parts of `Omit` leading to a deferred conditional here. Maybe i'll find out more later.

---

PS: the problem comes from an attempted solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65973328/tagged-class-with-assignability-to-untagged-default), just as context if needed.

Comment: Please keep in mind, `P extends string` is not the same as `string extends P`. Could you please write to function implementations where `string extends P` return true and return false?

Comment: `type test = string extends number ? 'yes' : 'no'; type test2 = string extends string ? 'yes' : 'no'; type test3 = string extends 'str' ? 'yes' : 'no';` It's a test, whether the type parameter is the default `string` or a subtype, e.g. `'str'`. At least that's what i hope it does.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCA8AVaBTAHgFxQOwCYwgwCcBLbAc2gF5pDSKA+aAbwChoPpgB7bOgV2AZuRABQAHfgCMQJYNAxhyALmiIAlC2gBfdp0JgMcrkRSGU8AAqpMOfLWJlKNOk4ajFK6JfWqElpjZOYOhTDH4ibGhsFAB3OCt3T3UAblY9Dl1WbSA

Comment: What do you want to achieve by using conditional statement in return type? Maybe it worth to use overloading

Comment: That the `tag` is either visible, or not. You can look at the question linked in the PS for more context.

Comment: here https://catchts.com/api you can find type logic for hiding method/property which is depend on generic value.
Also, this answer might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658633/how-to-determine-the-type-of-generic-in-a-class/65664455#65664455